# scala main method called twice

Tags: java, scala, jvm, sbt, multiple-instances

The main method is being called twice hence getting print and asking command line input twice

```scala
object Controller {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println()
    var path=""
    if (args!=null) {
      for(arg<-args) {
        if (arg.contains("path")) {
          path = arg.substring(5)
          println(path)
          println("Please enter the string to search ")
          val inStr=scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
          println("String entered is "+inStr+"\n")
        }
      }
    } else {
      println()
      println("agrs was null")
    }
  }
}
```

Created jar and executed with command

`scala simplesearch_2.13-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar path=Alpha`

**Output**
[image: Output]

[image: All args println]

Comment: Can you please change your program and print all args first with `args.foreach(println)`. Please update your answer with new output.

Comment: `args` will never be `null` also, this can't be all the code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: the second image contains output of args.foreach(println)

Comment: After moving the code to a method in separate class, and creating an object to run that method the twice issue goes away

Comment: @Programmeur Please create an answer with your solution